# Query sharepoint table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

I am using cakePhp to query a MSSQL table from Sharepoint. I have no control over the column names, so I cannot create an auto-incremented 'id' for the PK.

I would like to query the table via my 'Users' controller (which already has its own model). Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Sharepoint and CakePHP... Wow, this is fitting a square peg a mile wide in a 4 inch round hole. What's the schema of the Sharepoint table?

Comment: The schema has a composite primary key, each column consisting of hexadecimal characters. I am simply querying the database...going through the whole model process seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CakePHP does not support composite primary keys. They usual workaround (add a new column with a simple, singular primary key and put a UNQIUE constraint on the columns that used to be the composite key) doesn't work for you either, because you cannot change the schema.

It looks like your hosed. Couple of things you can do:

- Get a better ORM or PHP framework. One that does support composite primary keys (E.g. something that uses Doctrine 2). Honestly, CakePHP's ORM isn't that great.
- Use raw queries through the CakePHP database layer. You'll still get back nested arrays like you would when using a true CakePHP model. It may be enough for you, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, creating queries on the DB layer sounds perfect. After some searching, I am unable to find information on how to accomplish this. Can you lead me to a resource?